# Using UrlFetchApp.fetch() function to get Looker API access token and get timeout error

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to get the access token to access Looker Login page. Got Timeout error when running this code:

```
function getToken() {
var authPayload = {
    "client_id" : getProperty('authClientId'),
    "client_secret" : getProperty('authClientSecret')

};

Logger.log(authPayload);

var authOptions = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : authPayload
};

Logger.log(authOptions);

var endpoint = getProperty('apiEndpoint');
Logger.log(endpoint); 

var authResponseFull = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint + "/login", authOptions);

Logger.log(authResponseFull);
var authResponseJSON = JSON.parse(authResponseFull.getContentText());
Logger.log(authResponseJSON);
return authResponseJSON.access_token;
}
```

Error Logs:

```
[19-11-08 09:19:37:278 PST] {client_id=xcx64, client_secret=*****ghgGN}
[19-11-08 09:19:37:281 PST] {payload={client_id=xcx64, 
client_secret=*****ghgGN}, method=post}
[19-11-08 09:19:37:291 PST] https://abc.looker.com:19999
[19-11-08 09:20:07:281 PST] Exception: Timeout: 
https://abc.looker.com:19999/login
at getToken(Code:134:38)
```

I also tried this with hard-coded values and still got same error:

```
var authResponseFull = 
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://abc.looker.com:19999/login", 
                                       {
                                         'method' : 'post',
                                         'contentType' : 'application/json',
                                         'headers' : {'Api-key' : 'client_id=xcx64&client_secret=*****ghgGN'},
                                         'payload' : JSON.stringify(authPayload),

                                       });
```

Comment: Hello ntlh, welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please check whether you are able to get the token connecting from your personal computer? You can try using tools such as Curl, Postman or Insomnia. Thank you